# НЕ могу разобраться помогите выдает ошибку IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: scraping_vacancy.language_id

Tags: python, django

'''

```
import os, sys

proj = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('manage.py'))
sys.path.append(proj)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "scraping_service.settings"

import django
django.setup()

from sqlite3 import DatabaseError

from scraping.parsers import *
from scraping.models import Vacancy, City, Language

parsers = (
    (work, 'https://www.work.ua/ru/jobs-kyiv-python'),
    (djinni, 'https://djinni.co/jobs/?location=%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2&primary_keyword=Python')
)

city = City.objects.filter(slug='kiev').first()
language = Language.objects.filter(slug='python').first()

jobs, errors = [], []
for func, url in parsers:
    j, e = func(url)
    jobs += j
    errors += e

for job in jobs:
    v = Vacancy(**job, city= city, language= language)
    try:
        v.save()
    except DatabaseError:
        pass
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

я конечно не очень понял что происходит в том коде который ты прикрепил, но
корень ошибок такого типа чаще всего находится в файле models.py, вероятней всего ты несколько раз менял поля модели, затем создавал модели(записывал их в БД), потом опять менял конфигурацию модели, в результате этого возникли конфликты. В учебных проектах такого типа, я решал проблему удалением БД и миграций, проводил миграции и заново заполнял базу.